# How to normalize redux-form with react-native to prevent more input?

Tags: react-native, redux-form

Using: 
redux-form@7.3.0

```
<Field
    component={({ input: { onChange }}) => <TextInput onChangeText={onChange} />}
    name=‘truncate’
    normalize={(value) => value && value.toString().slice(0,2) || ''}
/>
```

When typing into this truncated field, the values displayed are not truncated.  I can keep typing past the first two characters and seeing the output.

I see only the first two characters in the truncate field value when submitting the surrounding form.

Why would the visible output not be truncated prevent more input?

Based on Charles response below, I also tried the telephone number example shown on the redux-form example page; the output is not normalized.

Attempting to recreate the telephone normalization shown from the example ends up with the same results - no normalization on the field displayed:

https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/normalizing/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your usage of the `normalize` prop, and apply the `maxLength` prop to your `TextInput`.

**Example:**

```
<Field
    component={({ input: { onChange }}) => <TextInput onChangeText={onChange} maxLength={2} />}
    name="truncate"
/>
```

---

Alternatively, you can try passing along the remaining input props to your `TextInput`.

**Example:**

```
<Field
    component={({ input: { onChange, ...remainingProps }}) => <TextInput onChangeText={onChange} {...remainingProps} />}
    name="truncate"
    normalize={value => value && value.slice(0, 2)}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks Charles!  My motive was more for a more complete validation and not specifically the length.  I am looking to prevent invalid characters from being placed into the field.  The above is the simplest test case I could show that reflects this.  I have tried working off of the phone number example in the documentation but it is not working the same for my react native component.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand what you're trying to achieve. Have you tried using the [`validate`](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/) prop?

Comment: Validate works fine for preventing the submission, but does not prevent invalid characters from being typed into the field.  Trying to prevent bad data from being entered into the form field in the first place.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include another example, which may be more along the lines of what you are after.

Comment: Yes that is what I am after, but it does not work - I can keep typing in text to the TextInput component.  On submission the value in the form is correctly spliced.  But even when passing in the value directly I am still not able to restrict the character input from the UI with normalize.

Comment: Strange. I tested this earlier today using an `Input` from the `react-native-elements` library, and witnessed the behaviour you are describing as desirable. I've amended my answer to provide a more general solution (but have not tested this, as I am currently on a mobile device). Give that a crack and see how you get on.

Comment: I am having the same issue when trying to limit the field to numbers only. It seems entering an invalid character gets parsed before updating the redux state so the value that redux receives hasn't actually changed, so no redux state updates are sent out so props aren't updating to correct the value in the input field. If I enter 1 or more invalid characters, then enter a valid character, the field is properly updated and the correct value is showing. Not sure how to get around this without implementing my own input parsing on every keystroke and manually removing the invalid character.